# I have a no-loop-func issue that I don't know how or if I should bother solving

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

Currently, this isn't breaking anything in my code but i keep seeing this is an error that usually causes serious issues but I don't know what's going on really or how to make the error go away. If anyone has any advice, that'd be great.

error: `Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'i'   no-loop-func`

Relevant Code Segment:

```
      let i = 0;
      let interval = moment()
        .day(days[0] + frequency * i)
        .toDate();
      while (moment(endDate).isAfter(interval)) {
        days.map((day) =>
          selectedDays.push(
            moment()
              .day(day + frequency * i)
              .toDate()
          )
        );

        interval = moment()
          .day(days[0] + frequency * ++i)
          .toDate();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the warning:

> Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'i'

Since your while-loop has only one function declaration (per iteration) we can assume that the following code is the problem:

> ```
> (day) =>
>   selectedDays.push(
>     moment()
>       .day(day + frequency * i)
>       .toDate()
>   )
> ```

The reference to `i` within the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) triggers the warning, because the JavaScript linter does not know when/where the declared functions are called.

When looking at the [`no-loop-func`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func) rule examples:

> ```
> for (let i=10; i; i--) {
>     var a = function() { return i; }; // OK, all references are referring to block scoped variables in the loop.
>     a();
> }
> ```

You can see that you can resolve this warning by using block scoped variables. When applied to your current code, it might look like this:

```
while (moment(endDate).isAfter(interval)) {
  // store the value used by the function in a block-scoped constant
  const period = frequency * i;
  days.map((day) =>
    selectedDays.push(
      moment()
        .day(day + period)
        .toDate()
    )
  );
  // ...
}
```

You should also avoid the use of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you are not going to use the return value. For just iteration use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

Another option would be to not declare a function at all, this can be done by using `for...of`.

```
while (moment(endDate).isAfter(interval)) {
  for (const day of days) {
    selectedDays.push(
      moment()
        .day(day + frequency * i)
        .toDate()
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```

The above removes the function declaration completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are declaring `interval` outside of your while loop and then modifying it inside the while loop.  This can lead to unexpected behavior. You can declare `interval` inside your while loop at the top and it will probably resolve the error/warning you are seeing.